# Backbone route on IE

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history

I'm trying use the history backbone root but it doesn't work fine on IE (or other browsers which don't support history api).

My webapp has this map, where **each module** makes a **request**, but **actions** should call a **function**:

- site/moduleA/
- site/moduleA/action1/ID
- site/moduleB/
- site/moduleB/action1/ID

mapping:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "moduleA/": "homeA",
        "moduleA/action1/:id": "action1", 
        // ...
    }
}

var app = new MyRouter();
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

I'm navigating using this:

```
app.navigate('moduleA/',{trigger:true});
```

or

```
app.navigate('/moduleA/action1/4334',{trigger:true});
```

(I'm getting links click events and calling *navigate(link.href,{trigger:true})* )

Every is working fine on Chr/FF (browsers with history api support), and the url is updated in the browser and the function is call.

However, in IE the url is replaced by this hash format: site/#moduleA/
In order to solve that I've tried set the root in history.start

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:'/moduleA/'});
```

But, now IE replace the url using this format: *site/moduleA/#moduleA/* or *site/moduleA/#moduleA/action1/432432*.

So, Why IE is repeating the root in the url ?
How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By setting `root` to `'/moduleA/'` you are telling backbone to use `site/moduleA` as the root, this is the expected behavior.

Rememeber in backbone

```
routes: {
    "moduleA/": "homeA",  // #moduleA/
    "moduleA/action1/:id": "action1" // #moduleA//action1/:id
}
```

is different from

```
routes: {
    "/moduleA/": "homeA",  // #/moduleA/
    "/moduleA/action1/:id": "action1" // #/moduleA//action1/:id
}
```

its good to keep this in mind when using `app.navigate`.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your information. I had many mistakes. I had to change all my links and remove from the href property the root part of the url. In addition, the Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:'/moduleA/'}); had to be different for no html5 browsers: Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:'/moduleA'+(Modernizr.history?'/':'')});
Since I'm setting the root property, It doesn't have to be in routes. In my example routes will be: { '/':'home', 'action1/:id': 'action1'}